# Conflict express.js response and Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have realized that express.js features:

```
response.render('page.html');
```

and

```
response.redirect('/route');
```

do not work when using Angular.js routing in the client-side. Particularly, when the commands are issued, nothing happens in the browser.

Is there any way to make them work, despite the use of Angular.js?

Comment: If you're using AngularJS as a Single Page App (and thus with SPA routing), which is the typical use, then requests aren't sent to the server when the url changes, as the page is not reloading at all, only the url changes and nothing else. The expected approach is that Angular would handle all of your routes and you would assign a controller/template for each route. The controller will use services to call the server for whatever information it needs in order to populate the template for that route.

Comment: This is basically what you need express to do: Serve your scripts, styles, etc `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));` and respond to all other requests with your Angular app's `index.html`:  `app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  var index = path.resolve(__dirname+'/public/index.html');
  res.sendfile(index);
});`